# ros1_bridge doesn't find ROS1 std_msgs/String type for chatter example

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I'm using ROS2 Foxy on Windows in one PC, and ROS1 Noetic on Linux in another machine. I want them to communicate.
I've compiled ros1_bridge following its [readme](https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge), knowing that for the Foxy pkg I need to [checkout](https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge/issues/385) the correct branch.

- I managed to build ros1_bridge correctly.
- The two machine are communicating in ROS2, which means I can see the topics and do the echo.
- The machine on Windows (ROS2 ) is publishing, the other (ROS1 and ROS2) is subscribed, I want to read the topic in ROS1. (I'm literaly doing the [example 1b](https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge))

Now, the bridge starts but **I get:**

```
created 2to1 bridge for topic '/chatter' with ROS 2 type 'std_msgs/msg/String' and ROS 1 type ''
```

While I am expecting:

```
created 2to1 bridge for topic '/chatter' with ROS 2 type 'std_msgs/msg/String' and ROS 1 type 'std_msgs/String'
```

**EDIT**: I noticed that adding --bridge-all-topics, I get the correct type for ROS1, but still the listener node doesn't print anything.
After some minutes it says: `Failed to connect to xxx.yyy.local:49195`

I did source ROS1 and ROS2 before the build, and if I do `rostopic type /chatter` I get `std_msgs/String`.

What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412760/ros1_bridge-doesn%27t-find-ros1-std_msgs/string-type-for-chatter-example/) by [alberto](https://answers.ros.org/users/93353/alberto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2023-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved myself, still I'm not sure how. The thing I did was to close the terminal dedicated to the bridge and re-do all the `source` (Linux), on Windows I did nothing.
Other things I did previously was:

- to remove the firewall with `sudo ufw disable`, because I wasn't able to see ros2 topics
- add `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311` and `export ROS_IP=127.0.0.1` in **.bashrc**. (Maybe this changes were crucial, and I didn't reopen the terminal after them)

Now everything works, tested also with a `PoseStamped` publisher/subscriber.

---

Originally posted by [alberto](https://answers.ros.org/users/93353/alberto/) with karma: 100 on 2023-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Davies Ogunsina](https://answers.ros.org/users/103873/davies-ogunsina/) on 2023-02-24**:
Great,happy it was solved.